# Oracle Forms - Error 103, Encountered the symbol "END"

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracleforms

I'm using Oracle Forms Builder 11.
My code:

```
declare 
    type myType is varray(3000) of my_table%rowtype;
    myAsset myType:=myType();
    i number;
    n number;
    exNoInvNum exception;   
begin   
    go_block('my_block');
    first_record;
    i:=1;
    loop
        myAsset.extend();
        myAsset(i).hqId:=:my_block.hqId;
        myAsset(i).deptId:=:my_block.deptId;
        myAsset(i).invNum:=:my_block.invNum;        
        exit when :system.last_record='TRUE';
        i:=i+1;
        next_record;
    end loop;
    go_block('my_block');
    first_record;
    loop        
        if (:my_block.linkedInvNum is not null) then
            n:=0;
            select count(*) into n
                from my_table s
                where s.invNum=:my_block.linkedInvNum
                and s.hqId=:my_block.hqId
                and (s.deptId=:my_block.deptId
                or (s.deptId is null and :my_block.deptId is null));
            if (n=0) then
                for i in myAsset.first .. myAsset.last loop
                    if (myAsset(i).invNum=:my_block.linkedInvNum
                    and myAsset(i).hqId=:my_block.hqId
                    and (myAsset(i).deptId=:my_block.deptId
                    or (myAsset(i).deptId is null and :my_block.deptId is null))) then
                        n:=1;
                    end if;
                end loop;
            end if; 
            if (n=0) then
                raise exNoInvNum;
            else
                commit_form;    
                go_block('my_table');
                clear_block(no_validate);               set_item_property('my_block.generate_excel',ENABLED,property_true);             set_item_property('my_block.process_data',ENABLED,property_false);
            end if;
        end if;
        exit when :system.last_record='TRUE';   
        next_record;
    end loop;
    exception
        when exNoInvNum then
            message('No existing inventory number!');
        when others then
            null;
    end;
end;
```

I get **Error 103 ad line 2, column 1: Encountered the symbol "END"**

I checked my code for typo errors, missing semicolumns and similar stuff, but it looks like everything is fine.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I get Error 103 ad line 2, column 1: Encountered the symbol "END"

Well, you do have an extra **`END`** keyword in your PL/SQL block.

> ```
>     end;
> end;
> ```

The syntax for an anonymous **PL/SQL block** is:

```
DECLARE
   ...
BEGIN
   ...
EXCEPTION
   ...
END;
```

And, this:

```
when others then
   null;
```

is itself a bug in your code.

A **when others** is almost always a **BUG** unless it is immediately followed by a **RAISE**. Remember, for errors, `RAISE –> CATCH –> HANDLE`. why do we need an exception handler? To catch the errors, log them(optional), and finally do something about them.

Read [WHEN OTHERS THEN NULL – A bug](http://lalitkumarb.wordpress.com/2014/05/02/when-others-then-null-a-bug/)

Comment: Thanks, I missed that one extra "end".

Comment: And as for the "when others then null"... I have nothing useful to say in my defense other than "that's the way it's always been done around here" :)

Comment: @vtomic85 Thanks for the feedback. Regarding WHEN OTHERS, it is a bad coding practice. It would be a good opportunity for you to propose a better code. Good luck!